# Spring Boot how to return two entities with one nested inside another when a look-up table connects them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, nested

Given a Spring Boot Java representation of a database containing 2 tables and a lookup table between them, with one to many relationships between the two tables and the lookup table, how does one return the two entities representing the main tables in a nested fashion?

At the moment, I can only figure out how to return them side by side, which is not a suitable response for what the front-end requires when it makes the request.

Controller left out for easiness - It just returns the service getAWithCNestedInIt().

```
    @Entity
    class A{
       @Id
       @GenereatedValue(strategy = "GenerationType.IDENTITY")
       @Column("a_id")
       Integer A_Id;

       Integer age;

       // Relationship with lookup table:
       @JsonIgnore
       @ToString.Exclude
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "BLinkToA")
       private Set <B> ASetLinkToB;
    }

    @Entity
    // look-up table 
    class B{ 
       @EmbeddedId
       BKey id;

       // Foreign keys to A and C
       @ManyToOne
       @MapsId("fk_A_Id")
       @JoinColumn("fk_A_Id")
       private A BLinkToA; 

       @ManyToOne
       @MapsId("fk_C_Id")
       @JoinColumn("fk_C_Id")
       private C BLinkToC; 
    }

    // B Key class here taken out to make code shorter.

    @Entity
    class C { 

       @Id
       @GenereatedValue(strategy = "GenerationType.IDENTITY")
       @Column("c_id")
       Integer C_Id;

       Integer foo;

       // Relationship with lookup table:
       @JsonIgnore
       @ToString.Exclude
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "BLinkToC")
       private Set <B> CSetLinkToB;
    }

    // A Controller calls and returns the following service method when URI "/getAandC" is hit
    @Service 
    class TheServiceClass {
       public List<List<Object>> getAWithCNestedInIt() {

          List <A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
          List<List <C>> cList = new ArrayList<C>();

          List<List<Object>> combinedList = new ArrayList <>(); 
          // Assume this method does work to get the desired aList and cList here
          /////////                                                     /////////

          int i = 0;

          for (A a: aList){
             List<Object> instanceOfBoth = new ArrayList<>();

             instanceOfBoth.add(a);
             instanceOfBoth.add(cList.get(i));

             combinedList.add(instanceOfBoth);
             i++;
          }
         return combinedList;
       }
}
```

Edit: JSON looks like this currently:

```
[[{ 
   "age: "123"
  },
  [{
    "foo": "456"
   },
   {
    "foo": "789"
   }]
 ],
 [{ 
   "age": "987"
  },
  [
   {
    "foo": "654"
   },
   {
    "foo": "321"
   },

   {
    "foo": "123"
   }
  ]
 ]
]
```

I want the JSON response to be this:

```
[[
  {
   "age: "123",
      CList:[{
             "foo": "456"
            },
            {
             "foo": "789"
            }]
  },

  {
   "age: "987",
      CList:[{
             "foo": "654"
            },
            {
             "foo": "321"
            },
            {
             "foo": "123"
            }]
  },
 ] 
]
```

Comment: How do you want to return them? As a list with Objects of class A and B? As a JSON?

Comment: Yes as JSON, sorry I put the JSON in an edit now ^.

Comment: Objects work too since the spring controller will automatically convert the code to JSON when sending a response to the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't simply create a representation of how your response should look and populate that representation with your entities?

```
public class ATransferObject {

    private Integer age;
    private List<CTransferObject> CList;

    // Methods omitted
}

public class CTransferObject {

    private Integer foo;

    // Methods omitted
}
```

This decouples your entities from the JSON representation and rather lets you control the representation exactly the way you want instead of mixing JPA and serialization in entities.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. I had not thought of that, it's a simple solution that works well.